# You must provide a user name/id (via --os-username, --os-user-id, env[OS_USERNAME] or env[OS_USER_ID]) or an auth token (via --os-token)

Tags: openstack

While trying to run `nova` command in *openstack* server, I get this error:

```
You must provide a user name/id (via --os-username, --os-user-id,
 env[OS_USERNAME] or env[OS_USER_ID]) or an auth token (via --os-token).
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: It's the problem of command's arguments. And plz show the `nova` command detail.

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply openrc file.

this file contains some env vars for user,pass,auth_url and ...

this file looks like this

```
export OS_USERNAME=username
export OS_PASSWORD=password
export OS_TENANT_NAME=projectName
export OS_AUTH_URL=https://identityHost:portNumber/v2.0
export OS_TENANT_ID=tenantIDString
export OS_REGION_NAME=regionName
export OS_CACERT=/path/to/cacertFile
```

or you can export one be one in bash. or permanently add to /etc/environment file.